# php for loop even odd generator missing last number

Tags: php, loops

I am using **for loop** for generating **Even , Odd numbers** from below code

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
        //echo even
        echo "Even: " . $i . "<br/>";
    } else {
        //echo odd
        echo "Odd: " . $i . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Its work well but little problem in even it not shown 100 number .I know that it is due to **$i < 100** so any hint How i can get 100 in list/generating

Comment: Either `$i < 101` or `$i <= 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$i <= 100` to include 100

Comment: Thanks for the ultra fast reply

Answer (score 1):

use $i <= 100 condition in your loop

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++){
    echo ($i%2 ? 'Odd' : 'Even') . ' ' . $i . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: +1 for using the ternary operator.